# Can it be proved that $f$ is integrable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, integration

Let $x$‎ be a differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$. I want to prove that for any time $t \geq t_0$‎
‎\begin{equation}
‎\frac{1}{2} D^{\alpha} x^2(t) \leq x(t) D^{\alpha} x(t)‎, ‎\ \ \forall \alpha \in (0‎, ‎1),
‎\end{equation}‎ 
where $D^\alpha$ is the Caputo derivative.
This is equivalent to showing that

‎$ x(t) D^{\alpha} x(t)‎ - ‎\frac{1}{2} D^{\alpha} x^2(t) \geq 0‎, ‎\ \ \forall \alpha \in (0‎, ‎1)$.

After simplifying we have:
\begin{equation}\label{11.67}‎
‎\biggl[\frac{[x(t) - x(t_0)]^2}{2\Gamma (1‎- ‎\alpha) (t‎- ‎t_0)^\alpha}\biggr]‎+ ‎\frac{\alpha}{2\Gamma (1‎- ‎\alpha)} \int_{t_0}^{t} \frac{[x(t)-x(\tau)]^2}{(t-\tau)^{\alpha+1}}  \,d\tau \geq 0‎.
‎\end{equation}‎

If we prove that the function $f(\tau)=\frac{[x(t)-x(\tau)]^2}{(t-\tau)^{\alpha+1}}$ is integrable, then the theorem is proved. Can this result be obtained?

Comment: For a  differentiable function $|x(t)-x(\tau)|^2=O(|t-\t|^2)$, $\tau\to t$, so yes function $f$ is integrable.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\tau \mapsto (t-\tau)^{-\varepsilon-\alpha}[x(t) - x(\tau)]^2$ is bounded on $(t_0, t)$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$. Then, up to a constant $C > 0$

$$\frac{[x(t) - x(\tau)]^2}{(t-\tau)^\alpha} \leq C (t-\tau)^{\varepsilon} \to 0 \text{ for } \tau \to t,$$

so we are in business with the limit term. Moreover,

$$\frac{[x(t) - x(\tau)]^2}{(t-\tau)^{\alpha+1}} \leq C \frac{1}{(t-\tau)^{1-\varepsilon}}$$

which gives integrability of $f$ at $t$.